# Add Azure Active Directory User in MVC Application

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, web-applications

I need help implementing access to users in Azure Active Directory. 
I would like to be able to search users within a tenant and add the user to an Enterprise Application that I have already created. 
The Enterprise Application currently allows me to add the user directly from Azure. 
I would like to be able to search for and add the user from the MVC application.
I would just like to be pointed in the right direction.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: use a search engine instead!

Comment: Thank you@astaykov. I've tried. I was hoping someone has probably experienced this before.